# How could i create a static string array using MEL as methodArguments of Invoke

Tags: java, mule

i try to call a method using the  component which takes a string and a string array.

flow.xml:

```
<invoke object-ref="ResponseHandler" method="nullPayload" methodArguments="#[message, #['getProducts', 'getProduct']]" />
```

ResponseHandler.java:

```
public class ResponseHandler
{
ResponseHandler()
{

}

public void nullPayload(MessageContext message, ArrayList<String> methods)
{
    message.setPayload("");
}
```

But when i try to run the application, the following error appears:

```
Single method "nullPayload", with "3" arguments not found
```

Any idea about how i could solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems. First, you should close the first expression in methodArguments and MEL syntax for array is { }, the expression will be:

```
<invoke object-ref="ResponseHandler" method="nullPayload" methodArguments="#[message], #[ { 'getProducts', 'getProduct' } ]" />
```

But this also fails because your method receives an ArrayList but you are sending an array. You should create an ArrayList in your MEL expression, but for what I saw this doesn't work well when you use generics. So, try using:

```
<invoke object-ref="ResponseHandler" method="nullPayload" methodArguments="#[message], #[ a = new ArrayList(); a.add('getProducts'); a.add('getProduct'); return a; ]" />
```

And in your code:

```
public void nullPayload(MessageContext message, ArrayList methods) {
    message.setPayload(message.getPayload() + "OK1");
}
```

I've also tried to change the method to receive a String[] but fails with the error you get, it seems that Mule is doing things bad here.

Comment: Hi, using your response i still have the same error, it still thinks that the method i try to invoke have 3 arguments.

Comment: You are right, I get the same, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: But the syntax is really less sexy now ! My purpose was to avoid having to initialize it like this (i can use groovy for this). Do you have any other idea?

Comment: There seems to be an error in the way that invoker parses the arguments, unfortunately I cannot find a better way to do it.

Comment: i will submit this case to mule support and keep you updated with their answer.